# Networkx: Calculating and storing shortest paths on a graph to a Pandas Data frame

Tags: python, list, pandas, networkx

I have a pandas dataframe as shown below. There are many more columns in that frame that are not important concerning the task. The column `id` shows the sentenceID while the columns `e1` and `e2` contain entities (=words) of the sentence with their relationship in the column `r`

```
id     e1        e2          r
10     a-5       b-17        A 
10     b-17      a-5         N
17     c-1       a-23        N
17     a-23      c-1         N
17     d-30      g-2         N
17     g-20      d-30        B
```

I also created a graph for each sentence. The graph is created from a list of edges that looks somewhat like this

`[('wordB-5', 'wordA-1'), ('wordC-8', 'wordA-1'), ...]`

All of those edges are in one list (of lists). Each element in that list contains all the edges of each sentence. Meaning `list[0]` has the edges of sentence 0 and so on.

Now I want to perform operations like these:

```
graph = nx.Graph(graph_edges[i])
shortest_path = nx.shortest_path(graph, source="e1", 
target="e2")
result_length = len(shortest_path)
result_path = shortest_path
```

For each row in the data frame, I'd like to calculate the shortest paths (from the entity in `e1` to the entity in `e2` and save all of the results in a new column in the DataFrame but I have no idea how to do that.

I tried using constructions such as these

```
e1 = DF["e1"].tolist()
e2 = DF["e2"].tolist()
for id in Df["sentenceID"]:
    graph = nx.Graph(graph_edges[id])
    shortest_path = nx.shortest_path(graph,source=e1, target=e2)
result_length = len(shortest_path)
result_path = shortest_path
```

to create the data but it says the target is not in the graph.

```
new df=

id     e1        e2          r     length     path
10     a-5       b-17        A       4         ..
10     b-17      a-5         N       4         ..
17     c-1       a-23        N       3         ..
17     a-23      c-1         N       3         ..
17     d-30      g-2         N       7         ..
17     g-20      d-30        B       7         ..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that's interested in the solution (thanks to [Ram Narasimhan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884035/networkx-calculating-and-storing-shortest-paths-on-a-graph-to-a-pandas-data-fra/50885433#50885433)) :

```
 pathlist, len_list = [], []
 so, tar = DF["e1"].tolist(), DF["e2"].tolist()
 id = DF["id"].tolist()

 for _,s,t in zip(id, so, tar):
     graph = nx.Graph(graph_edges[_]) #Constructing each Graph
     try:
         path = nx.shortest_path(graph, source=s, target=t)
         length = nx.shortest_path_length(graph,source=s, target=t)
         pathlist.append(path)
         len_list.append(length)
     except nx.NetworkXNoPath:
         path = "No Path"
         length = "No Pathlength"
         pathlist.append(path)
         len_list.append(length)

 #Add these lists as new columns in the DF
 DF['length'] = len_list
 DF['path'] = pathlist
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do what you are trying to do, in three distinct steps so that it is easier to follow along.

- Step 1: From a list of edges, build the `networkx` graph object.
- Step 2: Create a data frame with 2 columns (For each row in this DF, we want the shortest distance and path from the e1 column to the entity in e2)
- Step 3: Row by row for the DF, calculate shortest path and length. Store them in the DF as new columns.

#### Step 1: Build the graph and add edges, one by one

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

elist = [[('a-5', 'b-17'), ('b-17', 'c-1')], #sentence 1
         [('c-1', 'a-23'), ('a-23', 'c-1')], #sentence 2
         [('b-17', 'g-2'), ('g-20', 'c-1')]] #sentence 3

graph = nx.Graph()

for sentence_edges in elist:
    for fromnode, tonode in sentence_edges:
        graph.add_edge(fromnode, tonode)

nx.draw(graph, with_labels=True, node_color='lightblue')
```

[image]

#### Step 2: Create a data frame of desired distances

```
#Create a data frame to store distances from the element in column e1 to e2
DF = pd.DataFrame({"e1":['c-1', 'a-23', 'c-1', 'g-2'],
             "e2":['b-17', 'a-5', 'g-20', 'g-20']})
DF
```

[image]

#### Step 3: Calculate Shortest path and length, and store in the data frame

This is the final step. Calculate shortest paths and store them.

```
pathlist, len_list = [], [] #placeholders

for row in DF.itertuples():
    so, tar = row[1], row[2]
    path = nx.shortest_path(graph, source=so, target=tar)
    length=nx.shortest_path_length(graph,source=so, target=tar)
    pathlist.append(path)
    len_list.append(length)

#Add these lists as new columns in the DF
DF['length'] = len_list
DF['path'] = pathlist
```

Which produces the desired resulting data frame:

[image]

Hope this helps you.