# Is there a method to find depth of each node in a dataframe for a particular index?

Tags: python, pandas, depth

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns- pageurl, source, and target with pageurl as the index. The source and target are requests from each pageurl. I have converted the requests in source and target to numerical data.

I would like to know if there is a method to find the depth of each node respective to the index.

a sample of the dataframe.

```
                       source                   target
  pageurl
  www.google.com       1                         0
  www.google.com       1                         2
  www.google.com       2                         3
  www.google.com       0                         4
  www.facebook.com     5                         6
  www.facebook.com     5                         7
  www.facebook.com     5                         8
  www.facebook.com     5                         9
  www.facebook.com     10                        5
```

Expected Outcome

Would like to get the depth of each node with respect to the pageurl. It is with respect to pageurl because the same requests would be appearing in another domain also.

```
pageurl                node          depth
www.google.com          0              1
www.google.com          1              0
www.google.com          2              1
www.google.com          3              2
www.google.com          4              2
www.facebook.com        5              0
```

Goal:
At the end of this, I'm trying to find how a request might have different depth is different domains.

Note: 
The above dataframe is just a small part. My complete inspection is of 1 million Alexa sites.

Comment: What's your expected outcome?

Comment: @QuangHoang Sorry forgot to mention that. Have updated my initial question. Thank You.

Comment: This looks like a shortest path problem. Maybe `networkx` helps.

Comment: Thanks, @QuangHoang for your suggestion. The shortest path did help me to get the depth for each node. 
I also used some ideas from the following answer by Mi. and Ram Narasimhan

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884035/networkx-calculating-and-storing-shortest-paths-on-a-graph-to-a-pandas-data-fra?answertab=active#tab-top